# SVG animations' .beginElement() won't start in inserted SVG DOM in WebKit

Tags: xml, xhtml, animation, svg

I'm adding SVG with this code:

```js
$.get("/media/widgets/animation1/test.svg", {}, function(data, status, xhr) {
    var node = document.adoptNode(data.documentElement);
    $("#test").append(node);
});
```

XHR automatically recognized the mime type from the HTTP header so it gives me the XML Document. The image itself renders fine, but not any single animation declared by `<animateTransform>` or `<animate>` won't start, despite the fact that these element are parsed and inserted in the SVG DOM. My app is XHTML and the main `<svg>` element is properly namespaced.

I've also tried the `DOMParser` to create the DOM from string, but this throws errors for me.

EDIT: I've added `.beginElement()` call on all `<animate...>` elements, but with no results in WebKit (the browser I need).

EDIT: It works fine in Firefox 4 Beta 11.

Comment: Have you checked there is no such a bug in Webkit's bug database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beginelement is not implemented in webkit yet. See https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2010-September/245485.html